# Help with paper fan artwork; artist seal information (Characters identified: 滴水成河)

Tags: character-identification, seal

I was helping someone move from an apartment complex a few years ago and found some paper fan art in the dumpster. Can anyone help tell me what I have here and who the artist is or direct me to some resource that I can find out for myself?

thanks!'

-M

[image]

[image]